# Sum of column of nested grid using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

- Please see this fiddle, I want sum of nested grid and put sum value
  in text box of parent grid. This structure can repeat so I can't
  hard-code textbox name.
- HTML in fiddle is very messy but that is what generated from my page.

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/kashifnadeem/kGzFL/8/

- One another problem is that if I put this in Ajax (update panel) then
  this html is not generated why is that and how to use JQuery in that
  case.

Regards,

Comment: You now have 3 questions which are nearly the same (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552983/putting-sum-in-parent-td-using-jquery, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520051/calculate-sum-of-textboxes-inside-nested-grid). Maybe you need to break down you problem and don't ask for a complete solution for this problem.

Comment: The code is too messy. Your requirement is not very hard if you use well of class. Set class names for the td of your parent grid and table for you child grid. And query inputs with in the the td and child grid. It will be done. If you clean up your html(remove those auto generated names). I'll give you a full solution in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Chris Lee http://jsfiddle.net/kashifnadeem/kGzFL/8/

Comment: @Yoshi, I really need help in this. I am stuck and could not figure out solution. Sum of column and put it in parent td. I have tried but I am unable to find out solution of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/NyHa6/1/

Don't know whether this is what you want.